# Is there any way to use two styling conditions in a DIV block

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to use multiple styling statements for a single DIV block. I am not declaring the style statements in the style block at the head. Instead, i am trying to use styling for one particular DIV block like shown below. I am aware I can use ID's to give styling for individual blocks but am trying to do otherwise.
The output of the below code only applies the first style condition but doesn't give the indent.

```
<div style='float:left';style='text-indent:10px'>XXXXXX</div>
```

Comment: That's right, using multiple attributes with the same name is an error; you can't ever do that.

Comment: Then how do I give that block both the float and the indent attribute?

Comment: See @BarrJ's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
<div style='text-indent:10px; float:left;'>XXXXXX</div> //and so on
```